# ASP.NET Core 2 MVC App "POCO" Model binding not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I've got a pretty basic ASP.NET Core 2 Web App (no razor views, just MvcCore with json responses).

I'm trying to do a pretty simple GET request in Postman and my Controller Action isn't binding the query string parameters to my custom POCO.

here is a sample url which postman tries to hit: `http://localhost:51459/orders?Query=iphone&MinimumPrice=22`

```
public class OrderQuery
{
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public decimal? MinimumPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? MaximumPrice { get; set; }
}

[Route("orders")]
public class OrdersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetOrdersAsync(OrderQuery query)
    {
        // query.Query is null.
        // all the properties of query are null.
    }
}
```

Now I can step through the method (i.e. breakpoint is hit), so the route does get 'found' and 'handled'.

Secondly, I've also tried sprinkling `[FromQuery]` attributes on the properties in the POCO.

Lastly, I've tried changing the case in the request but I thought model biding is case insensitive.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Is there a particular `middleware` I should check to see if I've wired up/not wired up?

Comment: Try `Task<ActionResult> GetOrdersAsync([FromQuery]OrderQuery query)`

Comment: Nope - also didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

OMG @ me :(

So the variable name in the method signature is `query` and the (string) querystring key is also `query`.

The model binding was getting confused with *which* `query` do I mean? The property of the `OrderQuery` class? Or trying to set the string to actual method variable, which it cannot do.

Solution: renamed the entire signature to: `public async Task<ActionResult> GetOrdersAsync(OrderQuery orderQuery)`

** Note the method signature variable name change **

Doh! :)

TL;DR; Don't name the POCO variable name to a form/querystring/route key.